# My “register” function in pset9 is not working

Tags: cs50

What mistake am I doing in the code below for pset9 "register" function:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    elif request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 400)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 400)

        # Ensure password confirmation was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password-confirmation"):
            return apology("must provide password confirmation", 400)

        # Check if the password confirmation field matches the password field
        elif request.form.get("password-confirmation") != request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("Your passwords didn't match", 400)


        # Insert username and password into the database AND Hash user's password
        insert = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username,hash) VALUES(?,?)" , request.form.get("username"), generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        # Query database for that username
        row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Database
        database = db.exexcute("SELECT * FROM users")

        # Ensure username is not already in the database
        if row in database:
            return apology("username already exists", 400)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = insert

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")
```

ts giving me the below error:

row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username")) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The cause of a syntax error isn't always on the line where the error occurs. Often you should look at surrounding code, in this case the code above. Hint: Count your parenthesis

Comment: I think you need to be more specific since it's impractical for anyone else to run your code. Exact error?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikaelÖhman, that worked. Can't believe I missed that.

Why would the below line of code not work above:


`# Ensure username is not already in the database
   if row in database:
         return apology("username already exists", 400)`

Comment: Im not sure why the comment was removed and added back, but as I said, if something isn't working we would need to know what the error is.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman , it gives me **500 internal server error** instead of , **"username already exists"**

Comment: Also When I register a new user, the user gets inserted into the database but the page doesn't gets redirected to ("/"), instead it give me an **500 internal server error**